# How to pass generic list as constructor?

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist, .net-3.5

I'm new to C#. I came from Java.

In Java I usually pass ArrayList with data type in constructor.
In C#, it seems that ArrayList cannot take data type, and only List that can do it.

So I have this form which take List from other form

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private List<TestData> list;

        public Form2 (List<TestData> _list)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.list = _list;
        }
    }
}
```

If I did that, I got error like

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type is less accessible..

I've tried changing the private list to public but I got more error

> Inconsistent accessibility: field type is less accessible..

If I change the List to ArrayList. It's working.
Is it not possible to put the List in constructor in C#?

Comment: are you sure `List` is causing an issue.As i see the code above works perfectly fine.No issue except for a minor naming convention.Check if `TestData` class & its used properties are accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Problem is not with the class `Form2`. it looks fine. The Error message says that `Inconsistent accessibility:..` and you are accessing the class `TestData` inside here. So you have to Check the definition of `TestData` and confirm that it is defined as `public class TestData`

Comment: Thank you! I don't know the class is not 'public' by default. I'll accept the answer later :)

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private List<TestData> _list;
        public Form2 (List<TestData> list)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this._list = list;
        }
    }
}
```

Check whether 'TestData' is private or public and rename the private variable as in above code

Comment: Check whether 'TestData' is private or public

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `TestData` to be public

```
public class TestData
{

}
```

If `TestData` is `internal` (default if your wrote `class TestData`) or `private`, this means it is **less accessible** than the constructor which is public, and this is the error that you're reading.

So you have a constructor that can be accessed by anyone, using a type that is restricted. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggestion use the following sample and compare with your code and also declared other constractor and use.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Test> _property;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public Form1(List<Test> valueList)
        {
            _property = valueList;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        private string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Other form:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Default Constractor.
            new Form1();
            // Secound Constractor.
            new Form1(new List<Test>());
        }
    }
}
```

Tip: Test class must be public class.